# When is the Kernel Function added to the GPU's queue?

Tags: cuda

I need to know at what point of time does the kernel function get added to the GPU queue.
I did an ltrace of the CUDA program and got several invocations like
1.cudaconfigurecall
2.cudamemcpy
and i also got cudaLaunch()
My question is does the particular kernel function get added when cudaLaunch is invoked or sometime before or after that.
Which is the function responsible for adding the kernel function to the queue.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function gets added when `cudaLaunch` is called. The prior API calls, such as `cudaSetupArgument` and `cudaConfigureCall`, reserve and intialise call a stack frame for the upcoming kernel launch, but the stack frame doesn't get associated with a given kernel function and doesn't get pushed to the device until `cudaLaunch` is called. All of these functions have their own documentation in the CUDA toolkit, you can read about them [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#group__CUDART__EXECUTION).